# Find the determinant of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

\begin{vmatrix} n & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & \ldots& 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0  &n-1 \\ 
0 &1 & 0 &\ldots &  0 & 0  \end{vmatrix}

I know that we nedd to solve by (-1)^(n,n-1...2,1)a1n a2,n-1...an,1
N{n,n-1..2,1) = 1+2+...+(n-2)+(n-1)= n(n-1)/2 
But I don't understand what is the total answer, like howwe are calculating (-1)^n(n-1)/2 * a1n a2,n-1...an,1
 
I  would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Use MathJax to typeset your question. As much effort as it takes, the answers are worth double.

Comment: I cannot fully understand what the given matrix is. Could you provide the details on the entries?

Comment: where is the non-zero location on the second last column of your matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose each of your column has a single non-zero element which takes value $n, 1, \ldots, n-1$ respectively.

Factorize each of the number out from the determinant, we get a factor of $n!$.

The remaining term is a determinant of a permutation matrix.

\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix} n & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & \ldots& 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots  &n-2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0  &n-1 \\ 
0 &1 & 0 &\ldots &  0 & 0  \end{vmatrix} &=  n!\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots& 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots  &1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0  &1 \\ 
0 &1 & 0 &\ldots &  0 & 0  \end{vmatrix}\\
&= n! \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0_{1 \times (n-2)} \\ 0_{(n-2) \times 1} & 0_{(n-2) \times 1} & I_{n-2} \\ 0 & 1 & 0_{1 \times (n-2)}\end{vmatrix} 
\\&=n!(-1)^{n+1}\end{align}

where the last expression is obtained by expanding along the second column.